# No mobile broadband wizard with a GOBI2000

Tags: network-manager, 12.10, thinkpad

My details:

- Thinkpad T410
- GOBI 2000 WWAN
- Ubuntu 12.10 with Gnome3

In Ubuntu 12.04, Debian Squeeze and Debian Wheezy my GOBI2000 works like a charm but in Ubuntu 12.10 the connection wizard doesn't show up.

I configured the card the normal way:

- added thnkpad ppa
- install gobi-loader-tp
- copied firmware files to /lib/firmware/gobi/ (the same files work under debian)

The card is correctly recognized and my SIM is detected too. the only problem is when I try to setup a new connection the wizard doesn't start. simply nothing happens.

Any idea?

Comment: Does it work if you just use the **gobi-loader** package from the Ubuntu repositories?

Answer (score 1):

I'm experiencing the same problem since upgrading to 12.10 but with a Huawei K3765 usb dongle.

---

I have a workaround. Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> (or open a terminal) and run `nm-connection-editor`. Then you can go for the Mobile Broadband tab and add a new connection.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Lenovo X201 which also has the Gobi 2000 and 12.10.

After I 1st installed Quantal a few days ago it actually picked up the card and connected using the BT Mobile sim I have installed.

Then I went to actually use it today the connection was no longer in the network applet dropdown....

I am assuming that the 1st time it worked was because the firmware had persisted from the previous windows install maybe....

Now I have it working again, what I did may help:

I had to add the `thinkpad-extras` ppa and install `gobi-loader-tp`.

In a terminal window (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/thinkpad-extras
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gobi-loader-tp
```

I then downloaded and installed the `lenovo driver package` to a windows VM and got hold of the firmware files from the install.

Then had to play about with different firmwares from the choices until it worked.

One thing to be aware of is that you must have all 3 files (`amss.mbn, apps.mbn, & UQCN.mbn`) in the `/lib/firmware/gobi` dir. As mine for BT Mobile UK were split across 2 dirs (6 & UTMS).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Gobi2000 only suppoirt kernel 2.x .., so I jsut run it on Ubuntu 10.04 :P

- My Note: [凍仁的筆記: 藉由 Gobi 2000 啟用 ThinkPad T410 行動網路 on Ubuntu 10.04](http://note.drx.tw/2012/05/enable-wwan-with-gobi2000-at-t410.html)
- Ubuntu Forums: Howto: Gobi 2000 generic GSM/UMTS on Thinkpads - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1593581